# Large Number Formatting

Tags: commcare

In my CommCare app, I want to display (for example) 100000 as 100,000.  What formula can be used to add commas into the appropriate spot in long number values?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you can treat numbers like strings in CommCare (meaning that you can use the string-length, substr, and concat functions to take apart your number and splice in the commas. [See more about how these functions work here](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/CommCare+Functions)).

If you know your numbers will have six digits, that's pretty easy. Try the formula:

> concat(substr(number, 0, 3), ",", substr(number, 3, 6))

You can adapt this solution to any number of digits, if you know the number of digits in advance. If you don't, just enumerate all the possibilities. Here's everything up to 7 digits (and you can keep going if you want):

> cond(string-length(number) < 4, number,
>
> string-length(number) = 4, concat(substr(number, 0, 1), ",", substr(number, 1, 4)),
>
> string-length(number) = 5, concat(substr(number, 0, 2), ",", substr(number, 2, 5)),
>
> string-length(number) = 6, concat(substr(number, 0, 3), ",", substr(number, 3, 6)),
>
> string-length(number) = 7, concat(substr(number, 0, 1), ",", substr(number, 1, 4), ",", substr(number, 4, 7)),
>
> number)

Note that the "cond" function is only available in CommCare 2.31 and later. If you're working with an earlier version of the application, you'll have to use some very nested if loops!

There's also a generalized solution that I worked through for fun, but it's too complicated to share here. If you want a programming puzzle, I encourage you to think about how you could use CommCare repeat groups to generate the concatentation directly.

Answer (score 0):

This expression will work for up to 9 digits (you can extend it if you want to accommodate longer numbers):

`concat(if(number < 1000000, "", concat(substr(number, max(0, string-length(number) - 9), string-length(number) - 6), ",")), if(number < 1000, "", concat(substr(number, max(0, string-length(number) - 6), string-length(number) - 3), ",")), substr(number, max(0, string-length(number) - 3), string-length(number)))`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how powerful commcare's regular expressions are, but you might be able to achieve this with one. See this stack overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721304/insert-commas-into-number-string/721415#721415